# Como extraer los datos de un Array, mostrar y guardarlos individualmente

Tags: javascript

Tengo un array

```js
var cantidades = [3882.26, 4374.62, 4929.44, 5554.61, 6259.07]
console.log(cantidades)
```

y quisiera mostrarlos en `<input>` por separados y posterior guardarlos, y bueno una de las cosas que tenia en mente era crear 5 variables con las posiciones y listo, pero se me olvidaba que la cantidad de números(datos) dentro del Array es dinámico, en este caso solo puse 5 cantidades pero pueden ser 3, 2 ,6 etc.

la otra idea que tenia era generar una tabla con esos datos pero nunca lo he hecho, si alguien tiene un ejemplo lo agradecería montón.

Comment: Qué quieres hacer con esos valores? Pregunto porque no necesitas 'Guardarlos' a menos que vayas a usarlos una y otra vez. Puedes hacer todo lo relacionado con un array en un ciclo o dos

Comment: @JorgeSolis, la cosa es que no tenia claro que iba hacer, pero necesitaba primero mostrarlos por separados y luego ya guardaba en BDD. pero igual ya hice la pregunta, y en teoría ya me la respondieron el resto me encargo yo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza un forEach para escribirlos:

```js
var cantidades = [3882.26, 4374.62, 4929.44, 5554.61, 6259.07]
cantidades.forEach( function(cantidad)
  {
    $('#midiv').append('<span>' + cantidad + '</span><br>')
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='midiv'></div>
```

Como no sé en qué `<input>` quieres escribirlos lo he puesto en un span y ahora puedes cambiarlo como lo necesites.

Comment: es casi lo que necesito pero ya con el hecho de que se pueda mostrar por individual, el resto me lo arreglo yo. gracias!

Comment: De nada, me alegro de haberte ayudado!